# async/await on CacheItemPolicy.UpdateCallback event and other event delegates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

How-to: Call await method from a delegate void event method?

Converting (an ASP.NET) app to async is an all in - granted. But what about the places where it is not supported?

```
var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
policy.UpdateCallback = CacheEntryUpdateCallback;

void VoidDelegate(CacheEntryUpdateArguments arguments) {
   // need this - but no can't do :(
   await SomeApi.AsyncOnlyMethodAsync(); 
}
```

Await is not allow there, so what to do? What is the *right* way of doing this? The question also, applies to event handlers on WebForms like `myButton.Commmand += new CommandEventHandler(VoidDelegate)`

Is it **A:**

```
void VoidDelegate(CacheEntryUpdateArguments arguments) {
   Task.Factory.StartNew(new Func<Task>(async () => {
     await SomeApi.AsyncOnlyMethodAsync();
   })).Unwrap().Wait();
}
```

This will work but spin up another thread? At least it will not make the thread avail for the pool and the purpose of async here is gone.

Or is this supported **B:**

```
async void VoidDelegate(CacheEntryUpdateArguments arguments) {
  await SomeApi.AsyncOnlyMethodAsync();
}
```

But this is a fire-and-forget - but cache update event needs to fetch the new data before returning result. Same goes for e.g. button command event - page could be completed before the command has finished.

Comment: Try `Task.Run(async () => away bla);`

Comment: @abatishchev There's no reason to be doing that.

Comment: I'd avoid calling a method `XXXDelegate`.  It's a method, not a delegate, so calling it a delegate when it's a method is very confusing.

Comment: @abatishchev: That will be missing the Wait and without the Unwrap it seems to be unstable on a massive scale. Info: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Comment: @Servy: The names here are pseudo / only to explain what it is/context etc.

Comment: Yes I missed `Wait()`.

Comment: So it was supposed to be - try `Task.Run(async () => away bla).Wait();`

Comment: @AndersMad That's my point though, when giving the methods names just to describe what they're doing, it's confusing when the names *describe something else*.  Using `VoidMethod` as a placeholder for a void method would be more descriptive.  It'd be like calling it `intReturningMethod` when it's a `void` method.  It's just confusing, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark any method that returns `void`, `Task`, or `Task<T>` as `async`.  Marking a method as `async` doesn't change the signature of the method, so you're allowed to simply mark `VoidDelegate` as `async` if you want it to `await` things.

Note that, since you now have an `async void` method, this will be a fire-and-forget method.  When someone invokes the delegate the method will return very quickly, while the asynchronous work continues to happen, and the caller will have no way of knowing when the work finishes, or if it errors.

Comment: You are pointing to solutiona B. But - If it's a fire-and-forget it won't work for either cache update (needs to fetch new data before returning result) nor the e.g. command event on a button - the page will stop executing (or other bad state) before the event command has been completed.

Comment: @AndersMad Then you either need to do the work synchronously, or update the callback to support asynchronous (i.e. Task, returning) callbacks, if you're able to.

Comment: So your saying that solution A is THE right pattern to use in code and that true async here is not possible (thread that released back to IIS/web server) until MS makes async events for (in this case) System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache?

Comment: @AndersMad No.  There's never a time where that's the proper course of action.  You're doing nothing constructive by using `Task.Run` or `Task.StartNew` here.  If you *really* need to do the work synchronously, just call `Wait` (or `Result`, as appropriate) on the task you already have.  Wrapping the task in another task just to unwrap it accomplishes nothing.

Comment: But just calling `.Wait()` will cause locking?! I have had many cases of this while going `async` and solution **A** seems to deal with a massive concurrent client scale - much better it would seem.

Comment: @AndersMad If there is a synchronization context set, and the method called posts callbacks to that sync context and it won't complete until they return and you synchronously wait on the task *then* you've caused a deadlock.  In such a case you're just using a roundabout way of removing the current synchronization context.